# Symfony - query update database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function, symfony

I have a function in my Symofny that needs to update boolean field on click. 
I am writing a query to execute it, but I think my syntax is not right.

```
return $this->getRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('aq')
        ->update('aq')
        ->set('aq.asked = 1')
        ->where('aq.asked = :asked')
        ->orderBy('aq.id', 'asc')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Comment: Why do you think this is a syntax problem? What is your question? See [ask]. The idea is you explain what you are trying to do, what you tried, and what results you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add setParameter() ,because you added `->where('aq.asked = :asked')` but didn't init the :asked parameter. 
**EDIT:**  Also you need to add repository name to getRepository()

```
return $this->getRepository('AppBundle:YourRepository')
        ->createQueryBuilder('aq')
        ->update('aq')
        ->set('aq.asked = 1')
        ->where('aq.asked = :asked')
        ->setParameter('asked', yourParameterValue);
        ->orderBy('aq.id', 'asc')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Comment: Which class do you call it from ?